# How to create on code only one JFrame instead of multiples?

Tags: java, jframe

I've been searching how to limit my jFrame to open only one each time it's clicked but no success aparently. My code is like this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    login = true;
    InserirCliente tela_inserir = new InserirCliente(login);
    jDesktopPane1.add(tela_inserir);
    tela_inserir.setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    login = false;
    InserirCliente tela_inserir = new InserirCliente(login);
    jDesktopPane1.add(tela_inserir);
    tela_inserir.setVisible(true);
}
```

And there is a JInternalFrame with:

```
public InserirCliente(boolean login){
    initComponents();
    if(login){
        jPanel1.setVisible(false);
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Pretty simple, just testing it all. But how could it be changed to display only the first one and not more then the first as it is beeing clicked? Are there handles so it receives if there are instances of the JInternalFrame already created?

Comment: Create a manager or factory which is responsible for creating/managing the frame. When it's requested to "open" the frame, it should check it's internal cache to determine if the frame exists or not and create it if doesn't and probably bring it to the front if it does

Answer (score 0):

First, make `tela_inserir` a public/private variable depending on your need:

```
private InserirCliente tela_inserir;
```

Now add the following method to your InserirCliente class:

```
public Boolean checkVisible(){
    if(jPanel1 != null){
        return jPanel1.isVisible();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now just check if the inner JPanel is null (Not yet created) and not visible when your buttons are pressed:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //Only show new panel if i is not already visible:
    if (tela_inserir == null && tela_inserir.checkVisible() == false){
        login = true;
        tela_inserir = new InserirCliente(login);
        jDesktopPane1.add(tela_inserir);
        tela_inserir.setVisible(true);
    }
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //Only show new panel if i is not already visible:
    if (tela_inserir == null && tela_inserir.checkVisible() == false){
        login = false;
        InserirCliente tela_inserir = new InserirCliente(login);
        jDesktopPane1.add(tela_inserir);
        tela_inserir.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sorifiend, I changed some things on the project and now I'm using a button to add a new address to the user. But your code doesn't work here. I created the private variable of the new JForm inside my "client creator" and with a new button "add address" I inserted your code. What is probably causing the error is the part 'tela_inserir.checkVisible()'. As I didn't know what was the jPanel1 of the function you wrote, I created a form and put it inside tela_inserir. Anyway, no luck, but thanks

Comment: But I used a static variable isOpen inside my inner form which can be manipulated inside the 'add address' button. So if isOpen is false, it can create the new JForm and set isOpen to true. When exiting the new JForm, isOpen equals false and everything goes by. :D